# An error occurred in phase mojoExecution with the exception org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Obfuscation failed (result=1)

Tags: maven, proguard

i get this exception when i try to run my Proguard plugin for Maven :

> An error occurred in phase mojoExecution with the exception
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Obfuscation failed
>   (result=1)

how can i get a more detailed log ?

Answer (score 2):

you can add the attribute -e to get the stack trace, and/or -X to get a full log of the maven execution, to the maven command line.

Comment: one way would be to add a "run external tools" job, set the "location" to the mvn.bat in your maven installation folder (in windows), set the "working directory" to ${project_loc} and "the arguments" to "-e clean install" for example. select your project and then run the job via the eclipse toolbar.

Comment: @Genjuro run "mvn clean install -e" command from current directory in cmd